# Bootstrap scrollable dropdown with content :after

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tryng to build a scrollable dropdown menu with Bootstrap, with a little triangle on the top margin.

I used the :after selector to style the triangle, and it works only if the dropdown is not scrollable.

As soon as i set the dropdown as scrollable, the :after class is ignored.

This is my custom css for scrollable-menu:

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.scrollable-menu:after {
    content:"";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #e3c7aa;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below link works with you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgrdm7jt/3/)

```
.scrollbar{ background-color:lightgray;height: auto;max-height: 200px;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y:scroll; min-width: 135px;margin-top: 0px; }
#ex4::-webkit-scrollbar { width:10px;background-color:#cccccc; } 
#ex4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color:#B03C3F;border-radius:10px; }
#ex4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background-color:#BF4649;border:1px solid #333333; }
#ex4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active { background-color:#A6393D;border:1px solid #333333; }
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxw6awna/1/)**

You can check with the Updated link let me know if it works with you.

Comment: The dropdown works, but i can't see the triangle on the top margin as i need

Comment: Can you show example what triangle are you talkin about.

Comment: You can check with the Updated link let me know if it works with you.  Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/gxw6awna/1/

Comment: This is a good workaround at the moment, i hope to find a better solution. Thank you